# Comma in propositional logic

Tags: logic

Can you tell me, what the exakt meaning of a comma in logic is?
I recognised different situations, e.g.:

```
3/(x-9) > 2/(x+2)
```

For the determination, if the denominator is equal to zero, the following is stated:

```
Denominator != 0 => x!=9, x!=-2
```

In this case the "," is meant as an "or" (in my opinion?). But I've also seen its meaning as an "and".
Is there any general rule about that?

Thanks for your help!

Best regards
Lukas

Comment: It's an _and_ in this case as well: ($x$ is not equal to $9$) _and_ ($x$ is not equal to $-2$). The context is paramount, but it's typically an "and".

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's meant to serve as the word "and" or to separate conditions. For instance, I don't use the comma when I write out my assignments, precisely to avoid ambiguity. So I won't write something like
$$ \mbox{denominator } \neq 0\implies x\neq 9, x\neq =-2  $$
but more like
$$\frac{3}{x-9}\quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{2}{x+2}\quad\mbox{are well-defined implies}\quad x\neq 9\quad\mbox{and}\quad x\neq -2.$$
which makes it clear that the "$,$" serves as the word "and". A priori, however, it is not clear.

Comment: I would not find that use of $\in \mathbb{R}$ as meaning "is well-defined" to be a good idea.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Interesting. Can you suggest an alternative or point out why it's dubious or ambiguous, even? Is the problem aesthetical in the sense that $\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}\in A$ doesn't look nice.

Comment: An alternative is to simply write "is well-defined". It is ambiguous because not everything is about the reals. Also, the usage here would suggest that if $x=9$ then the expression makes sense and just gives something not in the reals, which is very hard to justify.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Fair points. I adjusted my notation a bit.

Comment: Thank you, that made it clear for me.